# Call a class method after another has finished its execution

Tags: javascript, class, methods, callback

I'm trying to execute a class method after another has finished. The first one calls an API and fills an array and a dictionary. Then, the next method takes the data and creates a new dictionary. I cannot make it work sequentially, any idea?

I have tried to add callback when calling the first method, but it ain't working.

```
this.fillListDictionary(function(){
    this.fillCatDictionary();
});

fillListDictionary(callback) {
    this._categoryList = [];
    this._propertyDictionary = [];

    //Fill list and dictionary calling the API ()
    callback();
}

fillCatDictionary() {
    this._catDictionary = [];        
    this._categoryList.forEach((category) => {
        this._propertyDictionary.forEach((property) => {        
            if(property.properties.includes(category)){
                var f_index = this._catDictionary.findIndex(x => x.category == category);
                if(f_index >= 0){
                    this._catDictionary[f_index].dbIds.push(property.dbId);
                }
                else {
                    var cat = new Object();
                    cat.category = category;
                    cat.dbIds = [property.dbId];
                    this._catDictionary.push(cat);
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I'd like to make it work sequentially: `fillCatDictionary` has to execute after `fillListDictionary` has done its job.

Comment: We use Promises for API's not callbacks.

Comment: `fillListDictionary` appears to be synchronous. Why use a callback at all? Just call them one by one: `this.fillListDictionary(); this.fillCatDictionary();`

Comment: If I call them one by one, the second method doesn't run properly and the catDictionary remains empty. That is because fillCatDictionary needs to have this._propertyDictionary already filled.

Comment: I also tried to implement a promise but I get this error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

code: let promise = this.fillPropertyList().then(this.fillDictionaries);